# What part of speech is "difficult"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech

> It is exceedingly **difficult** to ascertain precisely what is meant by the word 'culture'.

That is a sentence from exercise for English learners where they are asked to determine the part of speech of the word in bold. My decision was that *difficult* is an adverb in this context because of an adverbial meaning but the author writes that this is an adjective. Who is in the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is correct in saying it as an adjective. The word in this sentence is a predicate adjective. **Is** is a linking verb, so the word will either be a predicate nominative or a predicate adjective. In this case, it is describing the pronoun **it** so it is an adjective. *It is difficult*.